# Circles in tSNE output

Tags: tsne

Does anybody know when tSNE produces circles as embeddings (as a property of the input features)?

[image: tSNE output]

I've ran tSNE with the default params in R Rtsne function.

Comment: More details would be helpful, but I'm pretty interested in this.

Comment: It seems like very little structure is found +  a relatively low perplexity number.

Comment: The perplexity was 30. I was wondering whether somebody knows what properties of input data produce circular tSNE output?

Comment: @Dave what kind of details would you need?